# Looking for a book about people using telekinetic powers enhanced by generators

Tags: story-identification

I read a book several years ago that had humans using psychic powers to shift/teleport cargo and things. I remember at some point the story was set on an orbiting space station of some kind and these people used their powers to move cargo containers around.

Another part, closer to the end of the book, had 2 very advanced/powerful psychics use their power to shift/teleport a spaceship of some kind to a location 20+ light-years away. They not only managed it, they also sent the ship back in time the 20+ years so that it would be immediately evident back at their location that they had been successful.

I have asked this before and had many people say it sounded like the Talents Universe series by Anne McCaffrey. Truth be known, I am unable to locate any excerpts online to see if it is accurate.

The only other thing I recall about the story is that psychics learned to use some kind of external generator to augment their powers exponentially.

I know it isn't much to go on, but anyone have any clues? Perhaps some online review with a chapter quoted? I would probably recognize it from that. Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, before reading your third paragraph I was sure that would be the answer. Unfortunately [wikipedia's](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Ride_Pegasus) synopsis is fairly poor (the books were almost pre the Internet age), but I do think that is what your are looking for.

Comment: You could get sample chapters from the [Amazon kindle store](http://amzn.to/1dG87gl) I suppose?

Comment: {nods} It matches on every mark except perhaps the time travel.

Comment: You should also take a look at The Tower and The Hive series as it is also set in that universe. The Talents of the Earth series is the story of how the Tower and the Hive universe came to be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like it is, indeed, Anne McCaffrey's *Talents of the Earth* series, specifically [*Pegasus in Space.*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345434676)

Here's an excerpt from the epilogue:

> Dirk laughed. “It seems we’re always talking
>   contracts!” But he shook his head, pointing to the monitor showing
>   where the Bradbury had been. “You’ve proven that you can send the
>   Bradbury somewhere—but it’ll be another forty years before even that
>   pet SPOT of yours will see the light of that starship shining back
>   from Capella.”
>      Peter’s eyes gleamed. “So
>   you’re saying, Admiral, that until we can prove that we have lifted
>   the Bradbury the forty-five light years to Capella, we will have a
>   hard time revising your contract with FT&T?”
>       Dirk Coetzer nodded. “I’m afraid so. I know
>   you can do it but others are going to want to see proof.”
>       “I told you so,” Johnny muttered to himself
>   smugly.
>      “Well, how about we step over
>   here,” Peter said, motioning the admiral toward Dash’s monitors, “so
>   we can discuss proof more objectively.”
>       Dirk sighed. “Peter, I don’t think there’s
>   much more to—” His eyes latched onto the telescope’s image of
>   Capella’s M-5 planet. “What’s that?” the admiral pointed to the
>   glittering speck now visible.
>      “That’s the
>   Bradbury orbiting Capella,” Dash Sakai said, somehow managing to keep
>   his voice steady as if he were reporting no more than a normal
>   arrival.
>      Dirk’s jaw dropped and he turned
>   first to Johnny, then to Peter, raising a finger accusingly. “You
>   knew! You lifted it back in time. Why didn’t you tell me? Do you know
>   what that means? Do you know how this will speed up our explorations?
>   How did you do it?”

Comment: Joe L. nailed it. I recognized the name Dirk Coetzer instantly. Thanks for taking the time to answer so concisely.

Comment: @Stainless Steel Rat: My pleasure. Glad to help!